# How to sniff packets from wireless Bluetooth keyboard and Computer with help of wireshark?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, wireshark, packet-sniffers, bluetooth-keyboard

I want to sniff packets between bluetooth keyboard and computer and analyse with wireshark.What setup I need to have to see the packet transfer via bluetooth/ble?

Answer (score 3):

You have some different options.

1. Use an air sniffer such as https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-sniffer-for-bluetooth-le. See their documentation for more info.
2. If you are on Windows, you can use USBPcap (https://desowin.org/usbpcap/). That will sniff usb traffic to/from your Bluetooth controller which includes the hci packets, which will indicate what's being sent over Bluetooth.
3. If you're on Linux, just run "sudo btmon" to print all hci packets to the console. Not really Wireshark based though.

Comment: There's also the [Adafruit Bluetooth LE Sniffer](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2269).